# Why one RDD count job takes so much time

Tags: apache-spark, count, hbase, rdd, bigdata

I used newAPIHadoopRDD() method to load the HBase records to a RDD and do a simple count job.

However, this count job takes lots of time far more than I can imagine. I checked the codes, I am thinking may be in the HBase, one column family just has too much data, and when I load the records to the RDD, so much data may cause the executors memory overflow.

Is that possible this reason cause the issue?

Comment: Unless you have an explicit `OutOfMemoryException`, you shouldn't worry about memory overflow. Regarding the `count`, it depends on your cluster resources and the structure of your data.

Comment: I didn't get the OutOfMemoryException. Seems our cluster resources are big enough. If that is caused by the structure of data, may be setting the scan column family can solve the problem.

Comment: I haven't got enough information at hand to help you further on this, try understanding the structure of data or by giving examples so we can help you advance on this.

Comment: @user2961484 is it require to load all records in spark job? What are you trying to do with all of that data?

Comment: Just count how many items in each table in HBase. As there are lots of data , one table gets 14 billion records, there are two column family in this table. The first column family doesn't have too much columns while the other has lots of columns. I thought the reason why the count job takes so long is because I scan both of the column families. As the second column family holds too much data, the executors memory can't hold all of them